# Directives interaction: require vs. events

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am playing around with AngularJS directives. While focusing on interaction between parent/child directives. I stumbled upon two different approaches, and I was wondering which one is better. Let me explain with an example:

Suppose we have a `calendar` directive. The directive interacts with a `Calendar` model which features the model for the currently displayed days, and additional info such as the currently selected day in the calendar. Moreover, in the template of the directive we have a list of `day` directives, one for each day in the model.

```
<calendar>
    <day ng-repeat="day in Calendar.days"></day>
</calendar>
```

Now, suppose that we want to click on a day and change the selected day in the `Calendar` model.

**APPROACH 1: SET METHOD IN CALENDAR SCOPE AND USE REQUIRE**

```
myApp.directive('calendar', ['Calendar', function(Calendar){
    return {
        ...,
        controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs){
            this.setSelectedDay = function(day){
                 Calendar.setSelected(day);
            }
        }
    }
}]);

myApp.directive('day', [function(){
    return {
        ...,
        require: '^calendar',
        controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs, calendarCtrl){
            $element.on('click', function(){
                calendarCtrl.setSelectedDay($scope.day);
            })
        }
    }
}]);
```

**APPROACH 2: EMIT EVENT FROM DAY**

```
myApp.directive('calendar', ['Calendar', function(Calendar){
    return {
        ...,
        controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs){
            $scope.$on('daySelected', function(event, arg){
                //this call should be wrapped in $scope.$apply
                Calendar.setSelected(arg);
            })
        }
    }
}]);

myApp.directive('day', [function(){
    return {
        ...,
        link: function postLink($scope, $element, $attrs) {
            $element.on('click', function () {
                //tell to my parents 'I have been clicked!'
                $scope.$emit('daySelected', $scope.day);
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

Now, since both methods seem to require an hierarchy of directives, I would say the second is better, as I don't inject `calendarCtrl` in `day`. But it everything was solvable through events, I guess `require` wouldn't exist. So my question is: **is one of these two approaches significantly better than the other? When should I prefer the first over the second (or viceversa), and why?**

Comment: This question is too subjective... there are other ways to do it as well which `IMHO` are better.  You could for example use a service to marshal communication between parent/child.

Comment: @Nix, the service is already there! (`Calendar.setCurrent`). But in order to call the method directly, `Calendar` should be injected in the `day` directive. IMHO, from a design point of view the `day` should't have access to the whole `Calendar`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought about this for a few days. Since it didn't trigger a discussion, I am posting my own answer.

**1)** Prefer **REQUIRE** when you have a fixed hierarchy of directives that need to communicate.

EXAMPLE:

```
<accordion-group>
    <accordion></accordion>
    <accordion></accordion>
</accordion-group>
```

In this case, when an `accordion` is open, it can exploit one method in the `accordionGroup` controller to close all the others.

**2)** Prefer **EVENTS** when you need to communicate that something has happened from a directive, but you don't know what will need to react to the event.